# String.equals() with multiple conditions (and one action on result)

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to do something like this in Java for Android (this is a pseudo code)

```
IF (some_string.equals("john" OR "mary" OR "peter" OR "etc."){
   THEN do something
}
```

?

At the moment this is done via multiple `String.equals()` condition with `||` among them.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Possibilities:

- Use `String.equals()`:

  ```
  if (some_string.equals("john") ||
      some_string.equals("mary") ||
      some_string.equals("peter"))
  {
  }
  ```
- Use a regular expression:

  ```
  if (some_string.matches("john|mary|peter"))
  {
  }
  ```
- Store a list of strings to be matched against in a Collection and search the collection:

  ```
  Set<String> names = new HashSet<String>();
  names.add("john");
  names.add("mary");
  names.add("peter");

  if (names.contains(some_string))
  {
  }
  ```

Comment: Java 9+ `Set.of("john", "mary").contains(some_string)`

Comment: Set.of from Java8 * :-)

Answer (score 68):

```
if (Arrays.asList("John", "Mary", "Peter").contains(name)) {
}
```

- This is not as fast as using a prepared Set, but it performs no worse than using OR.
- This doesn't crash when name is NULL (same with Set).
- I like it because it looks clean

Comment: somewhat late to the party, but for the null check, you should do "Peter".equals(name). That way you don't have a possible null object to invoke an operation on

Answer (score 8):

Keep the acceptable values in a `HashSet` and check if your string exists using the [contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method:

```
Set<String> accept = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"john", "mary", "peter"}));
if (accept.contains(some_string)) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: This is the most efficient and IMHO most legible way.

Answer (score 3):

Your current implementation is correct. The suggested is not possible but the pseudo code would be implemented with multiple `equal()` calls and `||`.

Comment: thanks. I used term pseudo just to indicate that it's not an excerpt of my code

Answer (score 1):

If you develop for Android KitKat or newer, you could also use a switch statement (see: [Android coding with switch (String)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367629/android-coding-with-switch-string/19722741#19722741)). e.g.

```
switch(yourString)
{
     case "john":
          //do something for john
     case "mary":
          //do something for mary
}
```

Comment: `Cannot switch on a value of type String for source level below 1.7. Only convertible int values or enum constants are permitted` as Android does not support Java 1.7 this solution doesn't work.

Comment: What if both cases are true?

Comment: You forget `break;`

Answer (score -1):

No,its check like if string is `"john" OR "mary" OR "peter" OR "etc."`

you should check using `||`

Like.,,`if(str.equals("john") || str.equals("mary") || str.equals("peter"))`

Comment: samir, up is a pseudo code :)

Answer (score -1):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("tom"); //the regular-expression pattern
Matcher m = p.matcher("(bob)(tom)(harry)"); //The data to find matches with

while (m.find()) {
    //do something???
}
```

Use regex to find a match maybe?

Or create an array

```
 String[] a = new String[]{
        "tom",
        "bob",
        "harry"
 };

 if(a.contains(stringtomatch)){
     //do something
 }
```