# How to create a generic varargs method?

Tags: java, generics

Could it be possible to create a generic and varargs method? I know how to write a varargs method but what if it is generic?I have read a lot of things but I'm confused.

Actually, it is something like this:

```
    ArrayList <Cell<E>> list=new ArrayList<Cell<E>> ();
    public ArrayList <Cell<E>> sum(ArrayList<Cell<E>> ... elements){
    ....
    }
```

Is it correct?

Comment: I've just posted some code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378673/how-can-i-open-up-my-equals-statements-to-accept-more-than-one-parameter-in-java/17378881#17378881. Exactly what you want.

Comment: It would be helpful if you included an example of what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean, like so (I will use an interface for demonstration)?

```
public interface Test<T> {

    public void someMethod(T... elements);
}
```

or

```
public static <T> someMethod(T... args) {
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible:

```
<T> void method(T... args) {
    //logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the same way you would create a generic method:

```
public <T> List<T> asList(T... items) {
    return Arrays.asList(items);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
  public <T> void varArgsWithGenerics(T... objects){

        }
```