# C# "or" operator

Tags: c#, string, operators

I have this code:

```
if (textBox1.Text == "one" || "two")
```

I have tried to use || and | to add more strings, but it says that it cannot be applied to operands of type "bool" and "string". How can I make this work?
Thank you.

Comment: what are the diferent cases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

or alternatively :

```
var strings = new List<string>() {"one", "two", "thee", .... "n"};
if(strings.Contains(textBox1.Text)){
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's even better for what I need.

Comment: Can you tell me why this is failing: `(c.Contains('All') || c.Contains('')) ? "[ClientText] LIKE '%'" : "[ClientText] = '" + c + "'";` cannot convert string to bool error.

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
if (textBox1.Text == "one" || textBox1.Text == "two")
```

Comment: @SandroMilhano OP -- my guess is you were doing `textBox1.Text == "one" || "two"`. You can't do that -- the left expression will get evaluated to a boolean, then you're left trying to evaluate `boolean || "two"`, resulting in the error you mentioned.

Comment: @tnw Exactly. that's what me too suspect!

Comment: Yes I was trying to do that :)

Answer (score 5):

You can't combine operators in the way I suspect you are trying:

```
if (textBox1.Text == "one" || "two")
```

You need to qualify each condition as follows:

```
if (textBox1.Text == "one" || textBox1.Text == "two")
```

There are ways to make this easier to do, see answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17815728/how-to-combine-operators-in-condition-statement) for an alternative way to do it

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to use:

```
var options = new [] { "one", "two" };
if (options.Contain(textBox1.Text))
    ...
```