# If statement to handle unexpected responses from users for guess a number program not working

Tags: java, if-statement, compiler-errors

I am currently working an a "guess a number" project and one of my requirements is to handle unexpected output from the user.I also would want to know where in the code I should put this piece of code because my code feels very disorganized.

Right not I am using an if statement that isn't compiling and i'm not sure why.

```
while (!text.equals("yes")){
  System.out.println("Is your number " + (guess) + "?");
  System.out.println("yes,higher,or lower");
  text = reader.nextLine();

  if (text.equals("higher")){
    min = guess + 1;
  }

  if (text.equals("lower")){
    max = guess - 1;
  }
  guess = (max + min)/2;

  if (text.equals("yes")){
    System.out.println("Yay! I guessed it.");
  }

  if (!text.equals("yes" || "higher" || "lower" || "ok")){
    System.out.println ("I dont understand " + (text));
    System.out.println("Is your number " + (guess) + "?");
    System.out.println("yes,higher,or lower");
  }
}
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
Think of a number between 1 and 1000
Type ok when you're ready
 ready
 You said ready
 I guess that means you're ready
 Don't forget your number
Is your number 500?
 yes, higher, or lower
 no
 I don't understand no
 Is your number 500?
 yes, higher, or lower
  lower
 Is your number 250?
 yes, higher, or lower
 yes
Yay! I guessed it
=======
//error with my code
exit status 1
Main.java:38: error: bad operand types for binary operator '||'
      if (!text.equals("yes" || "higher" || "lower" || "ok")){
                         ^
   first type:  String
  second type: String
 1 error
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String.equals() with multiple conditions (and one action on result)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10208052/string-equals-with-multiple-conditions-and-one-action-on-result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement should be:

```
if (!(text.equals("yes") || text.equals("higher") || 
      text.equals("lower") || text.equals("ok"))) {
    ...
}
```

Anyway I would recommend using a `switch` instead:

```
switch(text) {
    case "lower":
        ...
        break;

    ... 

    default:
        System.out.println ("I dont understand " + (text));
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for :

```
if (!text.matches("yes|higher|lower|ok")) {

  // ...

}
```

Here you check if the String `text` doesn't matches any of the following *Strings* :

- *yes*
- *higher*
- *lower*
- *ok*

Answer (score 0):

You can change your if condition to and that will do

```
text.matches("yes|higher|lower|ok")
```